# Moving to a custom domain in blogger spoiled my pagerank. Need help?

Tags: pagerank, 301-redirect, blogger

I had www.chankeypathak.blogspot.com as my blog on Blogger. I then purchased a domain www.chankeypathak.com and then I followed the procedure of redirecting all old pages to new ones (301 redirect). Everything is working fine. But the only problem is that I have lost my pagerank.

Before it was 2 for www.chankeypathak.blogspot.com and now it is showing unranked for www.chankeypathak.com

How can I get my pagerank back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new domain, chankeypathak.com, has not been indexed by Google yet, so it is too soon for any page rank to have been transferred or lost.

Give it some time (a few days to a few weeks, depending on how quickly your blog used to be crawled) for the Googlebot to index you. You can check how many pages in your site have been indexed using Google's Webmaster Tools

Answer (score 2):

Google's public PageRank values are only updated every few months, so a new site will not show any page rank until that gets updated.

But really, you should stop caring about PageRank. It's a pretty useless number that condenses *over a trillion* web pages into an integer between 1 and 10. Instead, look at your traffic - are you still getting the same number of visitors? Are you still appearing in search results for the same queries (either old site or new site)?

Comment: @It's a pretty useless number that condenses over a trillion web pages into an integer between 1 and 10.... Good one, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers :) - in order for PageRank and other signals to be passed from your blogspot.com URLs to your own domain name, you need to use 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new ones. That's the normal procedure when moving sites. Google is pretty good at keeping track of all of those signals with site moves if they're done properly.

You can confirm the 301 redirect by using a HTTP header checker like web-sniffer:
http://web-sniffer.net/?url=www.chankeypathak.blogspot.com

This should be a 1:1 redirect for all pages as well ( example.com/x123 -> newexample.com/x123 , not just the homepage). Usually, if one URL redirects properly, then the others will too, so there's usually no need to check them all.

Another thing you can do for a site move (the [help center](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105) has all of these) is to use the Webmaster Tools "change of address" feature, which you can do if you still have both sites verified in your Webmaster Tools account. It's not critical that you do that, but it can help to speed things up.

Once you're sure that the move is set up correctly, I wouldn't worry about the Toolbar PageRank. It'll come at some point, there's no use [fussing about it](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/beyond-pagerank-graduating-to.html) since you can't do more than set up a proper move.